# Symfony Encore/Webpack never completes

Tags: symfony, symfony4, webpack-encore

Anytime I try to run encore, it doesn't complete and hangs at...

```
$ /vagrant/app/node_modules/.bin/encore dev
Running webpack ...
```

I've removed `node_modules` and re-installed numerous times following the Symfony documentation. Tried using only `npm` and also tried only using `yarn`. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  I've included `package.json` and `webpack.config.js`, if there is anything else needed to help troubleshoot, please let me know.

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.20.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // the project directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath('/app/build')
    .setManifestKeyPrefix('build')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // uncomment if you use Sass/SCSS files
    .enableSassLoader()
    // uncomment to create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    // .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment to define the assets of the project
    // .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addStyleEntry('css/style', './assets/sass/style.scss')
    // .addStyleEntry('css/print', './assets/sass/print.scss')


    // uncomment for legacy applications that require $/jQuery as a global variable
    // .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I had to disable the `resolveUrlLoader` in my sass loader options.

```
.enableSassLoader(function(options) {}, {
    resolveUrlLoader: false
})
```